# Can I use taxonomy term id from URL as Contextual Filter to get entities of custom entity type (not node)?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities

As in question.

I have a View with Profile2 entity. Entity has taxonomy term reference field. I'd to filter entities by term. I tried, but no luck

Can I do it with Contextual Filter or I must use exposed filter form (Filter Criteria)?

Path is council/%

The display is a page.

Comment: did you create a page view? what did you put in the path section?

Comment: @Aboodred1 question edited

Comment: what is the path that you are using for taxonomy term?

Comment: I don't understand. I exporter a view. Please see: http://pastebin.com/vZ5x4dFi

Comment: the exported view is useful but I what am asking for is the term url. So once you click on the taxonomy term what do you get in the url?

Comment: @Aboodred1 - good suggestion, I got empty page (e.g. taxonomy/term/56)

Comment: are you using [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module?

Comment: I don't use Path Auto